# PubNub hereNow method not returning the expected uuids list

Tags: java, android, pubnub

I am using PUBNUB api in android application

i am setting the uuid like this

```
mPubnub.setUUID("customName");
```

in user application

and in client application i am invoking  herenow method inside presence callback

```
mPubnub.hereNow("Svnchannel", hereNowCallback);
```

but i am getting incorrect uuid list like this

```
"uuids":["80e3b23f-bad1-4b48-8e89-61c234400d25","50b5c464-cda7-49b8-8ab6-a84ec5de42a1","0465c47b-c03b-4c86-91c4-60ea7267f467"]}
```

what i am expecting like this

```
"uuids":["customName1","customName2","customName3"]}
```

what i am doing wrong? please help

Comment: I haven't used pubnub yet and just had a look at the [docs](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/android-java/presence). It seems that a call to `setUUID()` will check if the passed string correlates to a generated unique ID on the device; if yes, the previously created unique ID will be returned otherwise a new ID will be generated.

Comment: To extend on my previous comment: [this article](https://www.pubnub.com/knowledge-base/discussion/138/how-do-i-set-the-uuid) explains how to create and re-use UUIDs each time an application is used. HTH!

Comment: you need to set `mPubnub.setUUID("customName123")` before subscription.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/2779561/saveen did setting the UUID before you subscribe resolve your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Setting and Reusing a UUID with PubNub Android SDK

You need to set `setUUID(String uuid)` after you instantiate your Pubnub object and before you subscribe. Here's the short version of this code:

```
Pubnub pubnub = new Pubnub("<your_pub_key>", "<your_sub_key>");
pubnub.setUUID("1234-5678-9ABC-DEFG-HIJK");
```

It's a good idea to cache this UUID on the device to reuse it every time your instantiate Pubnub object. Or you might get the user's UUID from the user profile record in your database after they login to your server.

Here's a more complete solution for generating/caching/setting/reusing a UUID. This code might need some refinement/updating.

```
// creating the Pubnub connection object with minimal args
Pubnub pubnub = new Pubnub("<your_pub_key>", "<your_sub_key>");

// get the SharedPreferences object using private mode 
// so that this uuid is only used/updated by this app SharedPreferences
sharedPrefs = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

// get the current pn_uuid value (first time, it will be null)
String uuid = getResources().getString(R.string.pn_uuid);

// if uuid hasn’t been created/ persisted, then create
// and persist to use for subsequent app loads/connections 
if (uuid == null || uuid.length == 0) {
    // PubNub provides a uuid generator method but you could 
    // use your own custom uuid, if required
    uuid = pubnub.uuid();
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();    
    editor.putString(getString(R.string.pn_uuid), uuid);
    editor.commit();
}

// set the uuid for the pubnub object
pubnub.setUUID(uuid);
```

You should be using a different UUID for every device.